# Rails Rake Assets Precompile throwing NoMethodError for Engine routes dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have a sandbox app using the shopify_app engine.  Routes was removed in the most recent versions of the shopify_app gem, causing the following error:

```
 rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `routes=' for #<ShopifyApp::Configuration:0x007fcab708e448>
remote:        /tmp/build_5d0f45fef6ff96f0e7e2e5cebd603067/config/initializers/shopify_app_initializer.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_5d0f45fef6ff96f0e7e2e5cebd603067/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/shopify_app-6.2.1/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:31:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_5d0f45fef6ff96f0e7e2e5cebd603067/config/initializers/shopify_app_initializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

So I am trying to mount the engine in my application routes file.

Here is the rails mount line I have added in line 2, but the NoMethodError is unchanged after mounting the ShopifyApp Engine.  I am not understanding the fundamental problem or how to fix it.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount ShopifyApp::Engine => '/', as: 'shopify_app'

  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new, :as => :login
    post 'login' => :create, :as => :authenticate
    get 'auth/shopify/callback' => :callback
    get 'logout' => :destroy, :as => :logout
  end

  get 'modal' => "home#modal", :as => :modal
  get 'modal_buttons' => "home#modal_buttons", :as => :modal_buttons
  get 'regular_app_page' => "home#regular_app_page"
  get 'help' => "home#help"
  get 'pagination' => "home#pagination"
  get 'breadcrumbs' => "home#breadcrumbs"
  get 'buttons' => "home#buttons"
  get 'form_page' => "home#form_page"
  post 'form_page' => "home#form_page"
  get 'error' => 'home#error'

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I imagine the precompile is breaking on the .routes invocation but I need help making the next leap

```
ShopifyApp::Engine.routes.draw do
```

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Comment: Please post `config/initializers/shopify_app_initializer.rb`

Comment: Thanks Antarr, the existance of that file was the missing piece for me.  I removed the line config.routes = true based on an instruction from Kevin one of the shopify_app contributors and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line `config.routes` from **shopify_app_initializer.rb**--it was set to `false`.